# How to fill form fields in a site using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, url, autofill

I have a url of a webpage, and I want to login using MATLAB.
I already wrote a code to open the specific site needed, but I don't know how to fill the edit-texts (and then, click the 'LOGIN' button.

I ask this as a generic question but if an example needed so this is the url I want to login to: https://dory.os.biu.ac.il/StudentSystem/FinalGradeFrame.jsp

So, in this site I have 2 texts to insert - ID and password, and a submit button to click on.

I know it's not hard to do so in javascript, but I need MATLAB (or, if it's very complicated using MATLAB, Python)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it in MATLAB, but it is really, really easy using python's `selenium` package.  So I would recommend you use that.

Comment: Great, THANKS! Yet, I prefer using MATLAB, so if any other solution is available I would be happy to know it :)

Comment: MATLAB is domain-specific language for specific sorts of scientific computing.  It is almost always really bad at anything outside of this domain, and what you are trying to do is way outside that domain.  You are much better off using a general-purpose language like python or a domain-specific language designed for that domain like javascript.  It will likely ultimately be possible to do what you want to do in MATLAB, but it will be very painful and waste a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am working with python 2.7, maybe it's better to move on and get python 3.4? What are the differences between those versions? Is the selenium package works fine with both?

Comment: Python 3.4 is the future, I would advise using that.  I use Selenium with Python 3.4 all the time.  In my opinion it just has a nicer and cleaner syntax overall, fixing a lot of small quirks with Plasma 2.x.  It isn't a huge difference, though.

Comment: Even though I work with selenum my code isn't working. Maybe there's a problem in the site I'm trying to reach?
My code: 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://dory.os.biu.ac.il/StudentSystem/StudentLogin.jsp")
assert "Python" in driver.title
id = driver.find_element_by_name("Id")
id.send_keys("123456789")

passwd = driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
passwod.send_keys("1234")

sub = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='images/submit.gif']")
sub.click()

Firefox is open, but the textboxes are empty.

Comment: You should probably submit a separate question about that.